# Changing label_img.py in inception image classifier to accept numpy arrays (opencv images) instead of jpg files

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I am building an image classifier using the tensorflow for poets inception pretrained model. My model is trained and it works well. However, when integrating it into my application, I have run into a problem. The existing code reads a jpg (or other image format) file and creates a tensor which it applies to the model. I want to input a numpy array (opencv image) instead of reading the image from disk.

I have tried convert_to_tensor (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) but i am not able to use the result in the rest of the code.  Other methods refer to an older example from a deprecated repo that use something like

tfImage = tf.gfile.FastGFile(imageFileWithPath, 'rb').read()
run the network to get the predictions
predictions = sess.run(finalTensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': tfImage})

I have screwed up the indentation while pasting but you should be able to get the idea

```
def read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name, input_height=299, 
input_width=299,
            input_mean=0, input_std=255):
input_name = "file_reader"
output_name = "normalized"

if type(file_name) is str:
 file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
if file_name.endswith(".png"):
  image_reader = tf.image.decode_png(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                     name='png_reader')
elif file_name.endswith(".gif"):
  image_reader = tf.squeeze(tf.image.decode_gif(file_reader,
                                                name='gif_reader'))
elif file_name.endswith(".bmp"):
  image_reader = tf.image.decode_bmp(file_reader, name='bmp_reader')
else:
  image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                      name='jpeg_reader')
float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0);
resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, 
input_width])

elif type(file_name) is np.ndarray:
 tf_img = tf.convert_to_tensor(file_name)
 resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(tf_img, [input_height, input_width])
 normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])
sess = tf.Session()
result = sess.run(normalized)

return result

def classify(file_name,model_file = 
 "tf_files/retrained_graph.pb",label_file = 
 "tf_files/retrained_labels.txt",output_layer = "final_result"):



 input_height = 299
 input_width = 299
 input_mean = 128
 input_std = 128
 input_layer = "Mul"

 graph = load_graph(model_file)

 t = read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                              input_height=input_height,
                              input_width=input_width,
                              input_mean=input_mean,
                              input_std=input_std)


 input_name = "import/" + input_layer
 output_name = "import/" + output_layer
 input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
 output_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(output_name);



 with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
  start = time.time()
  results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                  {input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
  end=time.time()
 results = np.squeeze(results)

top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
labels = load_labels(label_file)

print('\nEvaluation time (1-image): {:.3f}s\n'.format(end-start))
template = "{} (score={:0.5f})"
for i in top_k:
 print(template.format(labels[i], results[i]))
```

The above code works when given a path to a file like it was intended, but my modifications to read_tensor_from_image_file use a numpy array give errors. I suspect i need to replace 't' to change it to a tensor operator for output_operations. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feed the np array of the right shape directly for session evaluation, it should run as expected.

Here I used openCV to reshape/normalize the np array so the function should return the correct shape:

```
import cv2

def read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                                input_height=299,
                                input_width=299,
                                input_mean=0,
                                input_std=255):
    input_name = "file_reader"
    output_name = "normalized"

    if type(file_name) is str:
        file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
        if file_name.endswith(".png"):
            image_reader = tf.image.decode_png(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                               name='png_reader')
        elif file_name.endswith(".gif"):
            image_reader = tf.squeeze(tf.image.decode_gif(file_reader,
                                                          name='gif_reader'))
        elif file_name.endswith(".bmp"):
            image_reader = tf.image.decode_bmp(file_reader, name='bmp_reader')
        else:
            image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                                name='jpeg_reader')
        float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
        dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0);
        resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height,
                                                           input_width])
        normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), 
                               [input_std])
        sess = tf.Session()
        result = sess.run(normalized)

    elif type(file_name) is np.ndarray:
        resized = cv2.resize(file_name, (input_width, input_height),
                             interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        normalized = (resized - input_mean) / input_std
        result = normalized

    return result
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution worked for running the image, however, the classification was wrong, even though reading the original file gives the correct classification (with a higher confidence). The classification is highly dependent on color. Do you think that there is a problem with the rgb to bgr formats causing this? I am exploring that, Thanks.

Comment: Yes that could be RGB / BGR, you can try as its one line in openCV to convert but I dont recall having to convert my np arrays for use with inception. I also made a mistake for normalization if input mean is not 0. should be : `(resized - input_mean) / input_std` (Edited).

Comment: Note that I had to add a dimension using resized = np.expand_dims(resized, axis=0). @Terzirg your normalization edit is working! I removed my rgb bgr change and it classified it correctly, though the confidence is lower than reading the jpeg file from disk. Is it due to the interpolation methods possibly?

Comment: Great, yes the first dimension is the batch size. It's possible you can try different values for `interpolation` from here: `https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize`. Could also be the compression inherent to jpeg vs bpm vs png.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up doing things differently. I converted the BGR array to RGB and input the array into float_caster = tf.cast(file_name, tf.float32) and continued with the same functions as above.